# Magento 2: How to Track Product Price Changes different Admin User Wise?

Tags: magento2, admin, price, user-roles, admin-user

I have different Admin Users per Role. Need to track price change by particular User.

So Magento 2 is storing Old Price? Can we track from Initial Price to How many times price changed?

Suppose A User has changed Product A Price 5 times, then B User has changed same Product A's Price 3 Times?

Not sure maybe go for Custom Development. Will also need Product Wise Price Change Report (Admin User Wise)